# Return a string that has a variable inside a WordPress Shortcode

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

If I have this →

```
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="custom form" />
```

then I can easily convert this into a returnable string →

```
$output =  '<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="custom form" />'
```

Of course the output will later be returned:

```
return $output;
```

But this becomes challenging for me when It has a jQuery or a Wordpress Localized Function.

## Wordpress Localized Function

```
<input type="submit" class="one" name="aweber_submit" value="<?php _e("Subscribe", 'text-domain');?>" />
```

How to convert the above into a returnable string?
[P.S. → The php tags are actually not required because the shortcode function is in a file that is .php extension], but then If I just remove a PHP tag would that be ok?

```
$output = '<input type="submit" class="one" name="aweber_submit" value="_e("Subscribe", 'text-domain');" />'
```

Is this Ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost. Try this!

You need to break out of the string and concatenate whatever the function returns.

```
$output = '<input type="submit" class="one" name="aweber_submit" value="'._e("Subscribe", 'text-domain').'" />';
```

Comment: Why should OP try this? Can you explain the difference between your answer, and OPs attempt?

Comment: Yes, that's better :-) though there is missing a quote to close the value attribute, you now have `..value="something />`, which causes a syntax error on php and invalid HTML

Comment: well spotted! fixed

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the following to prevent the PHP function being stored as part of the string or in this case, causing a parse error because of the inverted commas.

```
$output = '<input type="submit" class="one" name="aweber_submit" value="_e("Subscribe", 'text-domain');" />'
```

to

```
$output = '<input type="submit" class="one" name="aweber_submit" value="'._e("Subscribe", 'text-domain').'" />';
```

Also note that the `_e` function will need to **return** a value for expected behavior.

Comment: You mean this → `'return $output';`